# Настройка https на nginx

Tags: nginx, безопасность, https, ssl

Подскажите конкретный пример, как настроить https на nginx.
С описанием- делаю это-> получаю это. Я не нашёл, как ни странно- всё очень запутано.  Что с сертификатами делать и можно ли их бесплатно сделать?
Вообщем для новичка в шифровании подскажите по частям.
Спасибо

Comment: Полезные ссылки: 1. [создание конфигурации](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), 2. [бесплатное получение сертификата с letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/).

Comment: Советую отличную статью по покупке и настройке https на nginx <a href="https://onlinebd.ru/blog/instrukciya-po-nastroike-https-dlya-php-fpm-s-ocenkoi-a">Полная инструкция по настройке HTTPS с оценкой А+</a>

Answer (score 3):

#### есть ли у вас план, мистер фикс?

1. вам надо сгенерировать или получить (бесплатно или за деньги) сертификат и ключ;
2. вам надо внести изменения в текущее содержимое секции `server`;
3. (опционально) вам надо создать ещё одну секцию `server`, перенаправляющую соединения, приходящие по http-протоколу, на протоколо https.

#### у меня есть три плана!

1. сгенерировать можно самостоятельно [с помощью программы `openssl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/4827341), получить бесплатно можно, например, в [центре сертификации let's encrypt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt), получить за деньги — в каком-нибудь [другом центре сертификации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
2. у вас есть секция `server` примерно такого вида:

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name ваш.домен;
     ...
   }
   ```

   вам [надо изменить директиву `listen` и добавить директивы, указывающие на сертификат и ключ](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html):

   ```
   server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name ваш.домен;
     ssl_certificate /путь/к/файлу/с/сертификатом;
     ssl_certificate_key /путь/к/файлу/с/ключом;
     ...
   }
   ```
3. при необходимости можно добавить ещё одну секцию `server`, в которой будет указано слушать протокол http и перенаправлять все обращения на протокол https:

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name ваш.домен;
     return 301 https://ваш.домен$request_uri;
   }
   ```

программу *nginx* после внесения изменений в конфигурацию, естественно, надо перезапустить.

Comment: ssl_dhparam, ssl_protocols, ssl_ciphers, HSTS?

Comment: @andreymal, да.